# Rails route to access files saved to tmp directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my background worker I'm creating a pdf and saving it to the `tmp` directory with:

```
save_path = Rails.root.join('tmp', unique_report_name)
File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
  file << pdf
end
```

I then try to open the pdf in a new window and get `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]` errors.

I've tried copying what they do with CarrierWave (I'm **not** using CarrierWave) by using the below in `config.ru`:

`use Rack::Static, :urls => ['/tmp'], :root => 'tmp'`

but I get the error `File not found: /tmp/my_file_name.pdf` even though the file does indeed exist in the location.

Comment: try removing the leading `/` ?

Comment: when I tried `use Rack::Static, :urls => ['tmp'], :root => 'tmp'`, I get `No route matches [GET] "/tmp/current_my_file_name.pdf"` again

Comment: If you run `rake routes` what does the relevant line of output look like? Also - yes it probably won't find the file in `/tmp/current_my_file_name.pdf` - because that is a hard-coded link to the actual root directory of your computer... not to the relative `tmp` path (relative to Rails root)... now we're just trying to figure out how it's getting that and what can be done to fix it... :)

Comment: The `tmp` path doesn't appear in `rake routes`. Should it appear there if I'm adding it in `config.ru`?

Comment: it should appear in rake routes if you want  your app to use it...

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to reach that file using Rails.root

```
"#{Rails.root}/tmp/my_file_name.pdf"
```